# How to get identity under which web app runs (ApplicationPool identity) when Thread.CurrentPricipal is null?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-8, windows-server

I have deployed asp.net core 2.2 web app as a WebSite to IIS. I've set the application pool identity to ApplicationPoolIdentity:

[[image: IIS Screenshol[1]]

Following line is throwing NullReferenceException:

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name
```

How should I get the user name under which the process runs?

Comment: Not sure what do you want . If you want to get the user's name using windows authentication , you could click [here](https://richhewlett.com/2011/02/15/getting-a-users-username-in-asp-net/) for code sample base on different IIS configuration .

Comment: Well, I don't want to get logged in user, but identity used to run the process. e.g.`IIS AppPool\MyApplicationPool` or `MyComputerName\SomeUser`